# WLAN and Bluetooth not working

Tags: networking, iwlwifi

I'm having an issue with my WLAN not working on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation. I updated to 20.04 because I hoped that this might solve the issue, but it didn't help. Will still stick with Ubuntu 20.04.

The WLAN is not even seen in the setting and in the taskbar. I did a lot of researching but so far nothing helped.

Here is the output of the WLAN Script. Can anybody help me? I really don't know how to solve this issue.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/c2P35pKYVj/

Comment: This is a kernel bug.

Comment: Is there a workaround? I updated to a newer kernel (5.7.8) and it did not solved the issue. https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:8086-9df0-8086-0034&page=8#status. Here its said the the device works using kernel 5.7.